# Why does this Margin push the element over its parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website that has a sidebar with some anchor links on it, and a search bar above it. It can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSpW8.jpg).

As you can see from the image, the search bar is pushed up right against both sides of the sidebar. I'd like the search bar to be a bit smaller and in the center of the sidebar, so I tried adding a 5px margin around it, but that simply pushed the search bar out over the right-hand side of the sidebar.

Here is my current CSS

```
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #484848;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  line-height: 75px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
}
.chat-header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    line-height: 75px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    border-left: 1px solid #484848;
}

.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  /*font-family: FontAwesome;*/
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  background-color: #3ab795;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 80%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #3ab795;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #484848;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.search-menu{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #484848;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

As you can see from the image, I also have another problem where the "active" css only seems to cover 95% of the sidebar. Is there an error in the CSS causing that?

Thanks!

EDIT: Forgot the HTML!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EB_MQ Message Centre</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="chat-header" class="chat-header"></div>

        <div class="nav-side-menu">
            <div class="brand">User ID</div>
            <div class="search-menu">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
            <div id="menu-list" class="menu-list"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need a [mcve]. Post your HTML as well.

Comment: @j08691 Whoops sorry, forgot that!

Comment: Your HTML does not include the Chat elements, so it's hard to check. Here's a codepen for you to edit and add what's missing: http://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/wojRvq

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz Sorry forgot that I create them with JS! Here's the codepen with the added JS http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyjvGX. Problem with codepen (and jsfiddle) is that the screen becomes small enough where the "active" css problem doesn't appear.

Comment: What about adding padding to `search-menu`? `padding: 0 40px;`

Comment: @mhatch Wow, thank you! That was really obvious, can't believe I didn't think of that. Now just to fix the "active" css problem.

Comment: Can you describe it better? I'm not seeing what you're looking for.

Comment: @ConorWatson In the codepen everything looks ok.

Comment: @mhatch If you look at the link I posted you can see that when one of the Chats is selected it is highlighted in green. However the highlight only seems to go 95% of the way and doesn't fill the whole sidebar width. Note: This isn't visible in the codepen because the screen is small enough to hide the problem.

Comment: When I post the code to a new page, the problem doesn't appear. What is different between the image and the codepen? Or, how can I reproduce it?

Comment: @mhatch Hmm really? That's very odd. I just copy and pasted the code from the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyjvGX and it produced the problem in Chrome and IE. It only seems to appear when the page is maximised.

Comment: @ConorWatson I promoted to an answer and updated the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For active class add `padding-right: 100%;` to the following css rule

```
.nav-side-menu li a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
}
```

To make the search smaller just add padding to `search-menu`

```
.search-menu{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    padding: 0 40px; /* whatever value you want, can be percent also */
}
```

```js
// Wait for the page to load first
        window.onload = function() {

          var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
          var newUL = document.createElement('ul');
          newUL.id = 'menu-content';
          newUL.className = 'menu-content collapse out';

          for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            var newLI = document.createElement('li');
            var newA = document.createElement('a');
            newA.id = 'chat' + i;
            newA.className = "chat";
            newA.addEventListener('click', chatClick, false)
            newA.setAttribute('href', "#");
            newA.innerHTML = "Chat" + (i + 1);
            newLI.appendChild(newA);
            newUL.appendChild(newLI);
          }

          toAdd.appendChild(newUL)
          document.getElementById("menu-list").appendChild(toAdd);

          var chats = document.getElementsByClassName("chat");
          chats[0].click();
          
        }

        function chatClick(){
            var title = document.getElementById("chat-header");
            title.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            
            var chats = document.getElementsByClassName("chat");
            for(var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++){
              chats[i].className = "chat";
            }
            this.className = "chat active";
        }
```

```css
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #484848;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  line-height: 75px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
}
.chat-header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    line-height: 75px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    border-left: 1px solid #484848;
}

.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  /*font-family: FontAwesome;*/
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  background-color: #3ab795;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #3ab795;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #484848;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.search-menu{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #484848;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat-header" class="chat-header"></div>

<div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">User ID</div>
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <div class="search-menu">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
    <div id="menu-list" class="menu-list"></div>
</div>
```